# MVC (Razor) Helper Class (ValidationImage) not rendering/working?

Tags: image, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to use the following helper class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace myNamespace
{
    public static class ValidationHelper
    {

        public static MvcHtmlString ValidationImage(this HtmlHelper helper, string name)
        {
            if (helper.ViewData.ModelState[name] == null || helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors == null || helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors.Count == 0)
            {
                return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
            }
                var tag = new TagBuilder("img");
                tag.Attributes.Add("src", "../Content/Images/check_bg_invalid.png");
                tag.Attributes.Add("alt", helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors[0].ErrorMessage);
                tag.Attributes.Add("title", helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors[0].ErrorMessage);
                tag.Attributes.Add("class", HtmlHelper.ValidationMessageCssClassName);
                return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
        }
    }
}
```

And using this in a view:

```
@Html.ValidationImage("FirstName")
```

to try and get an image to fire when there is a validation error.

So I have my:

```
@Html.TextBox("FirstName", null, new { @class = "my_input" })
```

in the same view (all within the @Html.BeginForm)

This is my model.cs class:

```
 public class QuoteModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must specify a First Name.")]
        public string First Name { get; set; }

    }
```

And this is my controller.cs class:

```
public ActionResult Quote()
{
    //return View();
    var model = new QuoteModel();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Quote(QuoteModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("QuoteSuccess");
}

public ViewResult QuoteSuccess()
{
    return View();
}
```

Bear in mind, I may have made a typo in all of the preceding code blocks.

Originally, I used

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("FirstName")
```

and the Error Message would fire after clicking send.  I am trying to now use the above helper for ValidationImage, but nothing fires (and the Error Message doesn't show).  Nor is anything output with an `<img>` tag.  No errors are thrown on the page.

As an aside, I have two other questions:
1) I would also like to display a validation success message (i.e., a little image with "OK"), but am having trouble just getting above to work in the first instance.
2) I was previously unsuccessful (before using helper) to get client side validation to show.

Am using

```
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }
```

in that same view.  I placed it at the top (after @model). Does placement matter?

I also used the following in my _layout.cshtml

```
<script language="javascript" src="@Url.Javascript("jquery.validate.min")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="@Url.Javascript("jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Note that I use a helper, so no need for ".js" extension - this has worked in the past and shows up in view source.  So no problems there.

Finally, I do have my web.config set up thusly:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Any thoughts on either of my problems (particularly the main one) are much appreciated.

Comment: I hate to ask but have you put a breakpoint in your `ValidationImage` method to check the values of the incoming data? (such as your Viewstate data`)

Comment: With so many views you'd think you people would upvote question/answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your validation image will only be output in the page if the server-side validation fails. This means your client-side validation can't possibly show the image, as it won't exist in the HTML markup (`return MvcHtmlString.Empty;`)

If you want the validation to work client-side (and show the image), you might have to do some work to hook into the existing validation. There's an article here about custom validation:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98376/Including-custom-client-side-validations-in-your-A.aspx

Though it might be a little overly complicated - there may be an easier way to hook into it (though I can't find one just now).